# PayPal REST API - Redirect Error Handling

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-rest-sdk

My question is simple yet I can't find any SO posts or PayPal documentation to answer it.

*In the event of a PayPal user having some error being redirected after completing their checkout (internet goes out, browser crashes, they close their browser before the redirect goes through, random networking issues, etc.) How are we suppose to handle that?*

I thought using the following REST API

```
GET /v1/payments/payment/<Payment-Id>
```

Would solve my problem but since the **state** returned from this request does not change from **created** to **approved** until the funds have been executed it is useless. In the case of having some redirect error you will not have been able to execute the funds and thus it will simply be in the **created** state still which does not help you.

Additionally I thought maybe PayPals IPN system used for `CLASSIC API` would be the answer to my problem but again it fails. The IPN system does not contain relevant information such as transaction ID which is needed to link the two systems together.

Is there no way to do automated error handling using the REST API?